# Audio Transformer with Center Tap to XLR Cable

Tags: audio, microphone

I would like to put an isolation transformer at the differential output of MAX4063 chip.

This [transformer](http://catalog.triadmagnetics.com/Asset/SP-67.pdf) has a center tap. Then at secondary side, outputs will be connected to a 3-pin XLR cable.

Is this a correct wiring?

I couldn't find anything similar with Google.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Looks good.  I've used versions of that xfmr, and as noted on the datasheet the low end performance is not great.

R3, R4, and the pin 2 connection to GND are not needed for audio reasons, but they don't hurt anything.

Depending on what the downstream circuit topology is, you probably do not need the pin 5 connection to GND.  In some cases it can reduce noise, while in others it can increase noise.  In the Shure and EV mics I'm familiar with, there is no centertap on the internal impedance-matching transformer.

Comment: thanks!         other end of the XLR cable will be connected to LINE IN of behringer ADA8200